# Continuously Send Data from Android Client to Python Server Socket

Tags: python, kotlin

I am currently trying to send ble data from the app to my PC using sockets. As of now, I am able to send data to the server, but the server only receives one data and then stops receiving. I am suspecting that there is something wrong with my client side code. Any help would be appreciated

My SocketClass code:

```
inner class SocketClass{
    fun doInBackground(message: String): String {
        try {
            socket = Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVERPORT)
            val outputStream = OutputStreamWriter(socket?.getOutputStream())
            val printwriter = BufferedWriter(outputStream)
            printwriter.write(message)
            printwriter.flush()
            printwriter.close()
            socket?.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }catch (e: UnknownHostException){

        }
        return ""
    }
}
```

and in the blereadcharacteristic I call the class in a thread like this:

```
private fun readDeviceCharacteristic(characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic) {
        var hashval:MutableMap<String, String> = mutableMapOf()
        var mainThreadList :MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
        var currentTime: String = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").withZone(
            ZoneId.of("Asia/Seoul")).format(Instant.now())  // Get current Timestamp
        if(idlist.size != 0) {
            readval = characteristic.getStringValue(0)
            valdata = readval.subSequence(3, readval.length).toString()
            idNo = readval.subSequence(0, 2).toString()
            parseList.add(readval)
            mainThreadList = parseList.toMutableList().distinctBy{it.subSequence(0, 2)} as MutableList<String>
            if(mainThreadList.size == maxConnLimit) {
                bleDataList = mainThreadList
                bleDataList.forEach{
                    hashval[it.subSequence(0, 2).toString()] = it.subSequence(3, it.length).toString()
                }
                loghash = hashval.toSortedMap()
                txtRead = bleDataList.toString()
                parseList.clear()
                if(isChecked) {
                    savehash["Time"]?.add("$sec.$millis")
                    bleDataList.forEach {
                        savehash[it.subSequence(0, 2).toString()]?.add(
                            it.subSequence(
                                3,
                                it.length
                            ).toString()
                        )
                    }

                }else{
                    time = 0
                    sec = 0
                    millis = ""
                }
                if(isInsert){
                    Thread{
                        SocketClass().doInBackground("$loghash\r\n\r\n")
                    }.start()
                }

            }
        }
        isTxtRead = true
        bleDataList.clear()
    }
```

My server socket python code:

```
    import socket
import sys

host = '19.201.12.12'
port = 30001
address = (host, port)

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(address)
server_socket.listen(5)

print("Listening for client . . .")
conn, address = server_socket.accept()
print("Connected to client at ", address)                                                  
while True:
    output = conn.recv(2048);
    if output.strip() == "disconnect":
        conn.close()
        sys.exit("Received disconnect message.  Shutting down.")

    elif output:
        print("Message received from client:")
        print(output)
```

I am able to get the first data sent, but do not receive anything after. Any help would be greatly appreciated thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Your server code only accepts one client connection.  So, here's the timelime.

1. Python waits at `accept`.
2. Kotlin connects
3. Python moves into `while True` loop.
4. Kotlin writes, then closes the socket.

At that point, nothing further will be received by the Python code, but because you never call `accept` again, you can't accept another connection.

You need to have the `accept` in a loop.  You handle that connection until it closes, then you loop to another `accept`.

You might consider using the `socketserver` module, which automates some of this.